# This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I get this error if I click a button that starts the backgroundworker twice.

```
This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Simple: Don't start the BackgroundWorker twice.

You can check if it is already running by using the `IsBusy` property, so just change this code:

```
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

to this:

```
if( !worker.IsBusy )
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
else
    MessageBox.Show("Can't run the worker twice!");
```

Update:

If you do actually need to launch multiple background tasks at the same time, you can simply create multiple BackgroundWorker objects

Comment: To some degree I agree that the answer isn't fully useful. Given the case you *do* need to run two background processes, it isn't great to get an error instead that says "Can't run the worker twice". I would assume the answer about running new backgroundWorkers for each task - or in some way queing the jobs is a better solution, that won't cause you to have to check if some other part of the system has already started the background job and act uppon that.

Comment: when exactly does `IsBusy` get cleared? i would have expected that it gets cleared just before the `RunWorkerCompleted` event is fired, but this doesn't seem to be the case (at least based on my experiments).

Comment: I don't think the OP's question has ever been answered. Although I think I did figure out part of my problem. I use a TcpListener in mine, and have while not pending cncel, accept connections. So I'm looking for some way to interrupt that call. The OP might need to provide more information on what he's doing with the BackgroundWorker to identify what's holding him up.

Comment: @omJohn8372 the OP asked "how can I avoid this error"? and the answer is "Don't start a background worker more than one time"

Comment: @OrionEdwards A technically accurate response that doesn't appear to have any value whatsoever.

Comment: @omJohn8372 that's about all the value it can have, given there is no other context from the OP other than "an error" and "how do I avoid it"... I would assume based on the fact that this answer is marked as the Accepted answer, that it did indeed solve the problem for the OP.

Comment: @omJohn8372 - if you're having issues with using TcpListeners in a background worker, my suggestion to you is not to do that. Use the async methods on the TcpListener, so things run asynchronously and free up your main thread to do other things. Most of the async methods take a CancellationToken which you can use to shut them down at any point, if you so desire

Comment: @OrionEdwards I appreciate the suggestion and it's a good one. I can't rightfully recall what I did to fix it, but I did get it fixed, without just trashing the old object and starting fresh. I did not go the full length of using the Async methods on the TcpListener, and I think I should -- I've stumbled upon them before and they seem like the concise way to handle things well.

Answer (score 54):

Create a new BackgroundWorker object for each operation that you want to perform. I.e., rather than:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
for (int i; i < max; i++) {
   worker.RunWorkerAsync(i);
}
```

Try this:

```
for (int i; i < max; i++) {
   BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
   worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
   worker.RunWorkerAsync(i);
}
```

Comment: That's a great answer. How do we kill all of the backgroundWorkers if required?

Comment: @VladSpreys I can't really discuss thread cancellation in just a comment, but there are some really good posts on this site on the subject.

Comment: @fatcat1111 thank you. I understand the idea of canceling the thread if we keep a reference to it. But with this code snippet we don't.

Comment: @VladSpreys if you want a list of references to the workers, then outside of the for loop declare a List<BackgroundWorker>, and in the loop, after instantiating the worker, add it to the list. Then if you need to cancel them, walk the list and cancel each by whatever means is best for your scenario.

Answer (score 6):

I would look into queueing the tasks that need to be done. You get the following advantages:

- You do not have to handle the problems of background tasks not being able to start due to something else already running
- You do not have to worry about using up too many threads, by creating a new background worked for each task.
- Lastly, the queue *could* allow you to ensure that the background tasks run in the same order as they where created/requested.

Here is an example implementation: *[broken link removed]*. I am not sure if the implementation in threadsafe, and I will update my answer once I figure out of my current locking problem in a implementation I am working with.

Comment: The link to the example implementation is broken

Comment: This answer is correct, but would be better with a code implementation rather than a link

Answer (score 2):

Although not the case originally asked by the OP, this can also happen due to a race condition (happened to me now, and looked for an answer) if you're using a Background worker in some sort of a producer-consumer pattern.

Example:

```
if (BckgrndWrkr == null)
{
    BckgrndWrkr = new BackgroundWorker(); 
    BckgrndWrkr.DoWork += DoWorkMethod;
    BckgrndWrkr.RunWorkerAsync();     
}
else if (!BckgrndWrkr.IsBusy)
{
    BckgrndWrkr.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

In this case there's a race condition: first instance instantiates a new background worker, 2nd instance reaches the `else if` and starts the background worker, before 1st instance reaches the RunWorkerAsync of the `if` block, and when it does it throws the error.

This can be avoided by adding a lock to the entire if + if else section.

Comment: Please don't ever name your variables like this.