# Multiple BackGroundWorker components in a single Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

Before discussing my problem, I want to know you about my stage.I am very new to C# programming. It is the first time I am working on it. So my knowledge in C# is very minimum.

I am developing my application using Windows Forms in C#. At some instant I was supposed to run 5 operations simultaneously . So that I tried the `BackGroundWorker` Component in the ToolBox of C#.

But using that, I could process only one of my operations among 5. I tried using 5 `BackGroundWorker` Components from the ToolBox and defined the `DoWork` functions seperately.

But when I called the `RunWorkerAsync()` function it threw an error saying "`backgroundworker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently`".

I don't whether I can use multiple `BackGroundWorker` in my program.Creating array didn't help me. Because I have a infinite loop to be run inside the `DoWork` functions of the `BackGroundWorker` components. If there is any other way to run 5 operations at the same time, Please help me get an idea about that. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace myapp5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);

            bw1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bw1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

            bw1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw1_DoWork);
        }

        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        BackgroundWorker bw1 = new BackgroundWorker();
        private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    videostream();
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        private void bw1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    videostream();
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (bw.IsBusy != true)
            {
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Background Worker is busy");
            }
        }
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
            {
                bw.CancelAsync();
                bw.Dispose();
                MessageBox.Show("Background Closed");
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bw1.IsBusy != true)
            {
                bw1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Background Worker is busy");
            }
        }
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bw1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
            {
                bw1.CancelAsync();
                bw1.Dispose();
                MessageBox.Show("Background Closed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the same BackgroundWorker instance?

Comment: [Agree](http://stackoverflow.com/a/588158/815938). You can't run another work while the worker is still busy, use _another_ worker.

Comment: No I am using different objects of the BackgroundWorker namely bw,bw1,bw2... etc., and calling the RunWorker function with the different object names. @Steve

Comment: _another_ meaning? Do you want me to use another object? If it is so I have done it. Still I couldn't make it happen. @kennyzx

Comment: Then it would be useful if you post your actual code. Perhaps just the lines that starts the worker threads

Comment: @Steve I have added my code above. Take a look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try thread for nominal use.

```
private object threadUnsafeObject;
    private object locker = new object();

    private void RunMulitpleThread()
    {
        object pass_your_parameter_here = "";
        for (int iCount = 0; iCount < 5; iCount++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(DoWork);
            thread.Start(pass_your_parameter_here);

        }
    }

    private void DoWork(object parameters)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            threadUnsafeObject = parameters;
        }
    }
```

Comment: dont use thread because its slow ... make use of ThreadPool for creating thread instead of creating thread directly....or make use of Task ...

Comment: you are right. though, above code is just for his reference in case he don't has to use BackgroundWorker.

Comment: So you are saying that I cannot use multiple BackGroundWorker in my program. Aren't you? @PranayRana

Comment: So you are saying that I cannot use multiple BackGroundWorker in my program. Aren't you? @RohitPrakash

Comment: @Dhivakarkanagaraj, you can use multiple backgroundworker, but not of same instance at the same time. You can create multiple backgroundworker.

Comment: @Dhivakarkanagaraj - i am saying you can use Threadpool to create thead rather than directly creating thread .....Or make use of Task Parallel library which part of new C# 4.0 it equalivalat of Background worker .....one disadvantage of using thread is you cannnot perform continuation once thread complete operation...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform 5 different function parallel than you need to 5 backgroundworker thread for that. One Backgroupwork thread is not sufficient for running 5 different function parallel.

You can also you TPL(taksparallel) library for this instead of backgroundworker.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your program have logical error so the same BackgroundWorker instance is used five times for calling RunWorkerAsync(). Review the code for this.

UPD

Your DoWork handler must look like this:

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    while (true)
    {
        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // perform work partially with short time!
            // and break the while loop at the end
        }
    }
}
```

UPD-2

Don't use Dispose() for workers.

Comment: I have added the my code above @Roman Bezrabotny could you please take a look at that?

Comment: Ok, I understand your issue. Please look attentively to this part of [CancellationPending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending(v=vs.100).aspx) help: "This property is meant for use by the worker thread, which should **periodically check** CancellationPending and abort the background operation when it is set to true."

Comment: so look my updating of answer

Comment: otherwise the handler aren't finished by CancelAsync() and background worker will be busy infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using  .net 4.0 or above, you should use Tasks. This is the direction where the .NET framework is moving. I've set up two fiddles for you to check out.
If you're using .NET 4.0 : https://dotnetfiddle.net/GUxD2j.
If you're using .NET 4.5: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NirDuU. This sample shows the use of the new await/ async  pattern introduced in the .NET framework